# Create a function with an argument as a subselect

Tags: postgresql, function, plpgsql

I'd like to create a function for select and changed me data

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION PublicatedTask( argument ) RETURNS SETOF task AS $$DECLARE
   f task%ROWTYPE;   
  BEGIN
    FOR f IN SELECT * FROM Task where layer IN $1 and publicationin<>0 ORDER BY id LOOP
      if (f.publicationIN = 1) then
    f.description='';
    end if;    
    RETURN NEXT f; 
    END LOOP;
    RETURN;
  END;
  $$
 LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

but I 'dont know what argument type?

I'd like to do `SELECT * FROM PublicatedTask((1,2,3));`

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or use `VARIADIC`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION PublicatedTask( VARIADIC argument int[]) RETURNS SETOF task AS $$DECLARE
   f task%ROWTYPE;   
  BEGIN
    FOR f IN SELECT * FROM Task where layer = ANY($1) and publicationin<>0 ORDER BY id LOOP
      if (f.publicationIN = 1) then
    f.description='';
    end if;    
    RETURN NEXT f; 
    END LOOP;
    RETURN;
  END;
  $$
 LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

And use it this way:

```
SELECT * FROM PublicatedTask(1,2,3);
```

`VARIADIC` is available as of version 8.4: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-VARIADIC-FUNCTIONS

Answer (score 0):

you could use an array of integers as parameter:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION PublicatedTask( argument int[]) RETURNS SETOF task AS $$DECLARE
   f task%ROWTYPE;   
  BEGIN
    FOR f IN SELECT * FROM Task where layer = ANY($1) and publicationin<>0 ORDER BY id LOOP
      if (f.publicationIN = 1) then
    f.description='';
    end if;    
    RETURN NEXT f; 
    END LOOP;
    RETURN;
  END;
  $$
 LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Then you could call it this way:

```
SELECT * FROM PublicatedTask('{1,2,3}');
```